# how to run commands (external) in gvim

Tags: java, vim

I am getting ready to write lot of small experimental java programs as I am studying for java certification. Since I want to avoid using an IDE I'm giving gvim a try.

I have a HelloWorld.java file open. How can I run `javac` and then `java` and then be able to see the output all in one window?

I do not want to alt tab to a dos prompt window. compile/run the program there and then come back to my editor.

Comment: If you were on a linux, it will show it inside the vim window itself, because the shell and the terminal emulator are separate. In windows, `cmd` is both the shell and the terminal emulator. There might be a work around which I'm not aware of (such as setting vim to use bash as the shell?)

Comment: Again, please. Why are you avoiding IDE?

Comment: @hasen thanks. I am on linux at home so will try that. 
@incarnate I would not avoid IDE in most cases but since preparing for certification I do not want IDE's help

Comment: @incarnate what's wrong with avoiding an IDE?

Comment: ah, I misread your last statement, I thought you knew about `!command` but were complaining that it opens a new window :P

Comment: @rogeriopvl Kidding, right? Java isn't a technology for notepads and vims. It doesn't mean you can't write a project without IDE, it means you'll give it up after 10'th misspelled word or 50'th forgotten import or 2'nd missing jar in your classpath. It also applies to learning Java, you'll get far more quick with intelligent IDE.

Comment: @incarnate i've been working with java for over 3+ years. know most about jars, classpaths, builds etc etc. but while preparing for certification i don't want the benefit of ctrl+space. anyways..

Comment: @incarnate, how dare you compare vim to notepad?

Comment: @incarnate 6 years of Java here, and never gave up of vim or textmate, but I did gave up on Eclipse and Netbeans pretty quickly. If IDE works for you, great! Use it and abuse it. But don't expect everyone to do the same.

Comment: Okay, okay! Tastes differ, really. Let's leave it at that. And yeah, +1 @hasen j =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in command mode:

```
:!javac HelloWorld.java && java HelloWorld
```

**Edit**: I believe that in windows do concatenate multiple commands you use `&&` and not `;` as I posted previously. But I'm not sure if this applies to gvim.

Answer (score 0):

You can run external programs from vim by prefixing the command you want to run with "!". For example you could run javac straight from gvim by typing ":!javac filename"